# Query to find active days per year to find revenue per user per year

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have 2 dimension tables and 1 fact table as follows:

**user_dim**

| user_id | user_name | user_joining_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Steve | 2013-01-04 |
| 2 | Adam | 2012-11-01 |
| 3 | John | 2013-05-05 |
| 4 | Tony | 2012-01-01 |
| 5 | Dan | 2010-01-01 |
| 6 | Alex | 2019-01-01 |
| 7 | Kim | 2019-01-01 |

**bundle_dim**

| bundle_id | bundle_name | bundle_type | bundle_cost_per_day |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | movies and TV | prime | 5.5 |
| 102 | TV and sports | prime | 6.5 |
| 103 | Cooking | prime | 7 |
| 104 | Sports and news | prime | 5 |
| 105 | kids movie | extra | 2 |
| 106 | kids educative | extra | 3.5 |
| 107 | spanish news | extra | 2.5 |
| 108 | Spanish TV and sports | extra | 3.5 |
| 109 | Travel | extra | 2 |

**plans_fact**

| user_id | bundle_id | bundle_start_date | bundle_end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | 2019-10-10 | 2020-10-10 |
| 2 | 107 | 2020-01-15 | (null) |
| 2 | 106 | 2020-01-15 | 2020-12-31 |
| 2 | 101 | 2020-01-15 | (null) |
| 2 | 103 | 2020-01-15 | 2020-02-15 |
| 1 | 101 | 2020-10-11 | (null) |
| 1 | 107 | 2019-10-10 | 2020-10-10 |
| 1 | 105 | 2019-10-10 | 2020-10-10 |
| 4 | 101 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-02-01 |
| 3 | 104 | 2020-02-17 | 2020-03-17 |
| 2 | 108 | 2020-01-15 | (null) |
| 4 | 102 | 2021-01-01 | (null) |
| 4 | 103 | 2021-01-01 | (null) |
| 4 | 108 | 2021-01-01 | (null) |
| 5 | 103 | 2020-01-15 | (null) |
| 5 | 101 | 2020-01-15 | 2020-02-15 |
| 6 | 101 | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-17 |
| 6 | 101 | 2021-01-20 | (null) |
| 6 | 108 | 2021-01-01 | (null) |
| 7 | 104 | 2020-02-17 | (null) |
| 7 | 103 | 2020-01-17 | 2020-01-18 |
| 1 | 102 | 2020-12-11 | (null) |
| 2 | 106 | 2021-01-01 | (null) |
| 7 | 107 | 2020-01-15 | (null) |

note: NULL bundle_end_date refers to active subscription.

user active days can be calculated as: `bundle_end_date - bundle_start_date` (for the given bundle)
total revenue per user could be calculated as : `total no. of active days * bundle rate per day`

I am looking to write a query to find revenue generated per user per year.

Here is what I have for the overall revenue per user:

```
select pf.user_id
    , sum(datediff(day, pf.bundle_start_date, coalesce(pf.bundle_end_date, getdate())) * bd.price_per_day) total_cost_per_bundle
from plans_fact pf
inner join bundle_dim bd on bd.bundle_id = pf.bundle_id
group by pf.user_id
order by pf.user_id;
```

Comment: Expected results will help us help you,, along with the logic you are using to define said results and your attempts. Also, please do format your sample data so that the data is aligned.

Comment: Looks like you need a `year` table. Is `start` and `end` type `date` or `datetime`, inclusive or exclusive? What do you want to show for years with no data?

Comment: @Charlieface years with no data could be shown as zero or null

Comment: the best way would be to prepare a fact table for that purpose, unless that query would be a heavy query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a 'year' table to help parse out each multi-year spanning row into it's seperate years.  For each year, you need to also recalculate the start and end dates.  That's what I do in the `yearParsed` cte in the code below.  I hard code the years into the join statement that creates `y`.  You probably will do it different but however you get those values will work.

After that, pretty much sum as you did before, just adding the year column to your grouping.

Aside from that, all I did was move the null coalesce logic to the cte to make the overall logic simpler.

```
with yearParsed as (

    select      pf.*,
                y.year,
                startDt = iif(pf.bundle_start_date > y.startDt, pf.bundle_start_date, y.startDt),
                endDt = iif(ap.bundle_end_date < y.endDt, ap.bundle_end_date, y.endDt)
    from        plans_fact pf
    cross apply (select bundle_end_date = isnull(pf.bundle_end_date, getdate())) ap
    join        (values 
                    (2019, '2019-01-01', '2019-12-31'), 
                    (2020, '2020-01-01', '2020-12-31'), 
                    (2021, '2021-01-01', '2021-12-31')
                ) y (year, startDt, endDt)
                    on pf.bundle_start_date <= y.endDt
                    and ap.bundle_end_date >= y.startDt

) 

select      yp.user_id, 
            yp.year,
            total_cost_per_bundle = sum(datediff(day, yp.startDt, yp.endDt) * bd.bundle_cost_per_day) 
from        yearParsed yp
join        bundle_dim bd on bd.bundle_id = yp.bundle_id
group by    yp.user_id,
            yp.year
order by    yp.user_id,
            yp.year;
```

Now, if this is common, you should probably create a base-table for your 'year' table.  But if it's not common, but for this report you don't want to have to keep coming back to hard-code the year information into the `y` table, you can do this:

```
declare @yearTable table (
    year int,
    startDt char(10),
    endDt char(10)
);

with y as (

    select      year = year(min(pf.bundle_start_date))
    from        @plans_fact pf

    union all
    select      year + 1
    from        y 
    where       year < year(getdate())

)

insert      @yearTable
select      year, 
            startDt = convert(char(4),year) + '-01-01',
            endDt = convert(char(4),year) + '-12-31'
from        y;
```

and it will create the appropriate years for you.  But you can see why creating a base table may be preferred if you have this or a similar need often.

Comment: `select pf.user_id, 
 sum(datediff(day, case when datepart( year, pf.bundle_start_date) < 2019 then '2019-01-01'else pf.bundle_start_date end,  case when pf.bundle_end_date is null or datepart( year, pf.bundle_start_date) > 2019 then '2019-12-31'
                       else pf.bundle_end_date end) * dp.price_per_day) total_cost_per_package
from plans_fact pf
inner join bundle_dim dp on dp.package_id = pf.package_id
where datepart( year , pf.bundle_start_date) <= 2019 and  (datepart( year, pf.bundle_end_date) >= 2019 or pf.bundle_end_date is null)
group by pf.user_id
order by pf.user_id`

Comment: I tried to limit the scope to get only 2019 revenue value by above query. but it doesn't work.not sure what am I missing

Comment: Using my query, not the one you have in the comments, add `where yp.year = 2019`.

Comment: awesome! but what's the reason of using cross apply ? can we not user regular joins ?

Comment: Join to what?  You already have bundle_end_date in the dataset in the plans_fact table.  Cross apply just creates a calculation for each row (sometimes returning more than one row, but not in this case).  I put the calculation that takes care of a null end date in it so that I wouldn't have to repeat the logic every time I wanted to reference the end date.